# Data_load_utility issue TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a data load utility and getting and error.

This method is part of one utility program I got in github which loads data.I'm using this for different scenarios. Almost all functions in this utility are causing the same issue. Using Python 3.x with Juypter notebooks.

https://github.com/SAP-samples/hana-ml-samples/blob/master/Python-API/pal/notebooks/data_load_utils.py

Code:

```
@staticmethod
    def load_shampoo_data(connection, schema=None, batch_size=10000, force=False,train_percentage=1.0,valid_percentage=0.0,test_percentage=0.0):
        if schema is None:
            schema = Settings.user
        full_tbl = "SHAMPOO_SALES_DATA_TBL"
        tables = [full_tbl]
        fq_tables = [schema + '.' + tbl for tbl in tables]
        cols = '( \
                ID INTEGER NULL,\
                SALES DOUBLE NULL\
                )'
        inlist = '("ID", "SALES") \
                    VALUES (?, ?)'
        DataSets.load_data_auto(connection, fq_tables, cols, inlist,'../datasets/shampoo.csv',train_percentage,valid_percentage,test_percentage, batch_size,force)
        if len(tables) == 1:
            return tables[0]
        return tuple(tables)
```

Error I'm getting:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 data_tbl = DataSets.load_shampoo_data(connection_context)
>
> C:\dir python util\data_load_utils.py in load_shampoo_data(connection,
> schema, batch_size, force, train_percentage, valid_percentage,
> test_percentage)
> 630         full_tbl = "SHAMPOO_SALES_DATA_TBL"
> 631         tables = [full_tbl]
> --> 632         fq_tables = [schema + '.' + tbl for tbl in tables]
> 633         cols = '( 
> 634                 ID INTEGER NULL,\
>
> C:\dir python util\data_load_utils.py in (.0)
> 630         full_tbl = "SHAMPOO_SALES_DATA_TBL"
> 631         tables = [full_tbl]
> --> 632         fq_tables = [schema + '.' + tbl for tbl in tables]
> 633         cols = '( 
> 634                 ID INTEGER NULL,\
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: Looks like schema is `None` (default parameter).  The error is telling you you can't use + on a type `None` here: `fq_tables = [schema + '.' + tbl for tbl in tables]`.  It is probably a bad idea to allow a default parameter of `None` if it will throw an error.  What ever calls this function should be sending a valid schema.

Comment: pls see I added details its still not working even if I change schema